# Gmail returns 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I found this error while i'm trying to send an email from one Gmail account to another. How to solve this error ? Help me on it.

There were an error:

> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 hw7sm51688135pac.12 - gsmtp

Comment: I followed but it displayed like "Can’t sign in to my email app" ..!!

Comment: I read it, but i didn't get the solution for my query. I gave correct Email Address and password. Can you please brief me what is the exact problem in this scenario ?

Comment: Thank you sir, i found the solution, Just "Turn On" the less security of your google account for send the email, "https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en" this link was the cure for me.

Answer (score 79):

You need to allow less secure apps, you can do it by click below link

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

also try this one

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

if still not works try changing password for gmail

Comment: Impressive, I had done both steps and at the end, changing the password fixed the issue. Thanks mate.

Comment: Welcome @Hassek

Comment: Less secure apps option was enabled for me, but the second option did the trick.

Comment: I had to change the password too

Comment: Thanks mate!! This saved me a lot of time :))

Comment: @G.AshokKumar, Its working for gmail, but what if the SMTP details from outlook.

Comment: Thanks really appreciated

Comment: Here you can also find additional steps how to unblock mail sending through Gmail https://serverfault.com/a/672182/277529

Comment: Thanks, This really solved the problem. Mine is working on localhost, but when I uploaded it to the server, it does not work on the server and to my surprise keeps working. So changing the password makes both to start working..

Answer (score 17):

You need to set the Allow less secure apps: ON, login to google using the account desired, and go to the [security page](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and set the `Allow less secure apps` to be ON.

Comment: it solved my problem with a smtp connection, thank you ;)

Comment: Here's the new direct link:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with all the below options none of them worked, changing the password solves the issues.

Allow less secure apps ON
Passed correct user/password
Tried this https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

All are correct in my case but still getting error Username and Password not accepted.

My Gmail password didn't change for a long time, after updating the password it works.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to send email with gmail stmp from 000webhost. In the error message there was this:"Gmail returns 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser". the problem was that google blocked the connection.
they asked if the connection request were from me. I haved change my password and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check multiple-factor authentication is off and the Less secure app is turned on as mentioned by others in this thread. If you still face the issue follow the below steps.

- On your computer, open Gmail.
- In the top right, click Settings and See all settings.
- Click the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
- In the "IMAP access" section, select Enable IMAP.
- Click Save    Changes.